# Synchronizing PowerShell background jobs

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, start-job

If two background jobs are started from the same session, how can one of them determine that the other has finished?
Initially I tried something like this:

```
$j1 = Start-Job {
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
    "j1 done"
}

$j2 = Start-Job {
    param($j)
    "j2 waiting..."
    $j | Wait-Job
    "j2 done"
} -ArgumentList $j1.Finished

$j1,$j2 | Receive-Job -Wait
```

Of course it doesn't work because `$j2` only gets a serialized snapshot of `$j1` (the job Status in the snapshot would never change); furthermore each background job has their own job repository so `$j` object appears to be bogus in the context of `$j2`.

The jobs can synchronize via the mutexes, filesystem (if on the same machine) or a DB, etc. but I'm wondering if powershell provides any remoting-friendly facilities for this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is going to work because the job objects are relative to their PowerShell session/runspace.  The `Start-Job` cmdlet spins up a new runspace (typically a new process).  I don't believe PowerShell events would work either because they also appear (according to docs) to be session specific.  I would keep it simple and use a file - pass the path into both jobs.

Comment: Yeah using files is OK (I used global mutexes, which I think are backed by the filesystem anyway) as long as everything's on the same machine, which is safe to assume given `Start-Job` (vs `Invoke-Command`).

Answer (score 0):

try this - in PowerShell 3.0 and newer:

```
$j1 = Start-Job {
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
    "j1 done"
}

$j2 = Start-Job {
    "j2 waiting..."
    $Using:j1 | Wait-Job
    "j2 done"
}

$j1,$j2 | Receive-Job -Wait
```